# /How do I tell how many devices are connected to my Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, networking, cmd.exe

According to the Windows 7 EULA and Net Config Server the maximum number ofconnections allowd to my windows 7 PC i 20. Netstat -a returns way more than 20 connections. I am trying to set up a business system and want to add more computers to connect to my CRM database. We are approaching close to 20 computers and so I need to find a way to increase it. Before we do I need to find out how many devices are currently connected. How do I do this? If I need to expand this in the future what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can get a list of currently logged on users by opening Task Manager and going to the Users tab. Are you looking for something similar, except through the basic command line (not the GUI, not PowerShell)?

Comment: Also, one question at a time please. (You can always post multiple question posts asking different questions, but it's usually a good idea to wait for one to be answered before asking a follow-up question.) How to get the list is one question; how to increase the allotment is another. Please [edit] your question such that it asks only a single question, Also, "best" is liable to becoming opnion-based, which is something we avoid here; better to just ask how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `net session` or `net session /list` to get an overview of connections to your machine.

Comment: When net config server says max connections=20 are these the connections it is talking about? I am assuming that these are the same 20 connections the EULA is talking about...

Comment: I believe so. I had a similar problem and came to this conclusion. Use `net session /delete` to close all connections (see `net session /?`).